# How to parse JSON data when the property name is not known in advance?

Tags: javascript, json, properties

Here is my response code in jQuery:

```
var response = $.parseJSON(response);

for (var i = 0; i < response.groupIds.length; i++) {
    console.log(response.groupIds[i], i);
}
```

Each `response.groupIds[i]` is of the form `{"unknown name":"unknown value"}`.

I wish to access both of these bits of data in javascript, how do I accomplish this when I don't know in advance what e.g. `unknown name` is?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to retrieve a full list (array) of key names. A polyfill is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatiblity).

```
var group = response.groupIds[i];

var allPropertyNames = Object.keys(group);
for (var j=0; j<allPropertyNames.length; j++) {
    var name = allPropertyNames[j];
    var value = group[name];
    // Do something
}
```

Your question's response format contains only one key-value pair. The code can then be reduced to:

```
var group = response.groupIds[i];
var name = Object.keys(group)[0]; // Get the first item of the list;  = key name
var value = group[name];
```

If you're not interested in the list, use a `for-i-in` loop **with** [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty). The last method has to be used, to exclude properties which are inherit from the prototype.

```
for (var name in group) {
    if (group.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        var value = group[name];
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for..in` loop:

```
for( x in response.groupIds[i]) {
    // x is now your unknown key
    // response.groupIds[i][x] is the unknown value
}
```

Since there is only one property of the object, that'll work nicely.

Comment: When I try this it says i is not defined?

Comment: Didn't you define it in your first `for` loop?