# Access to json variable (node.js)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How can I get the value "success" if the value that stands in place "Everlasting hair" is changing?

```
{ 
'Everlasting hair' :
   { succes : true,
     volume:'12'
   }
}
```

Comment: `Object.values(a)[0].succes`

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @Keith: Only on really cutting-edge JavaScript engines. :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728195/how-to-parse-json-data-when-the-property-name-is-not-known-in-advance

Answer (score 1):

You can discover the property names in the object via `for-in` or `Object.keys`. `Object.keys`, for instance, will give you an array of the object's *own, enumerable* properties. If you know for sure there will only be one, then:

```
var success = yourObject[Object.keys(yourObject)[0]].succes;
// Another s here? It's missing in the question -----------^
```

On cutting-edge JavaScript engines with `Object.values` (new in ES2017, but polyfillable), as [Keith points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718899/access-to-json-variable-node-js/47718952#comment82398127_47718899) if you don't need the name you can use `Object.values` instead:

```
var success = Object.values(yourObject)[0].succes;
// Another s here? It's missing in the question -^
```

Comment: yeah, it`s work! tnx a lot!